# Chrome tab customization on Flutter web

Tags: flutter

How can I customize the tab name and icon in browser tab for flutter app.
please check the image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'AppName',
  onGenerateTitle: (context) => 'AppName',
  // ...
);
```

Comment: It works! thank you very much. I think this is a bug in flutter. because the title should be enough

Comment: I'm glad it's working. I have no idea if this is a bug or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit title tag in your index.html  which will be available inside web folder.

For Example :

```
<title>Your App Name</title>
```

Comment: this does not work. changing the title only change the tab in chrome browser not in mobile browser when minimizing the tab

Comment: Did you tried clearing the cache and hot reload after this change have deployed ?

Comment: Yes. it works on browser tab on desktop. but if you try to open the application from chrome app on mobile and minimize the tab. you will see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

[Title widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Title-class.html) also works well including on mobile browser minimized tab.